# Maintaining a monorepo for a react project

Tags: reactjs, git, monorepo

What I am looking for is a master package/Sdk that defines my features, now I have various build version of this Sdk with customized features, now whenever I add a new feature to the master, it automatically reflects in the other build versions, I might have a lot of versions of it in the near future so the idea of keeping different repos/branches then merging them, later on, can turn into a nightmare( I do this right now).

I have thought of creating a configuration based system but as the sdk grows maintaining those configuration files will be a bigger challange than merging projects.

Android does something like this, example

I have my MainActivity( the top level file)

and I have a build version which has its own customized MainActivity

now When I update my top-level file, I see those changes in my build file too.

**Note:** All features added will not raise merge conflicts(As long as I am not updating old features). Any suggestion, StackOverflow reading recommendation will help.

Comment: Hi at work we are using *Lerna* which is great to manage a monorepo: https://github.com/lerna/lerna
_create-react-app_ and _babel_ to name few are also using it.

Here are some URLs on the topic I've been through: https://hackernoon.com/one-vs-many-why-we-moved-from-multiple-git-repos-to-a-monorepo-and-how-we-set-it-up-f4abb0cfe469
https://medium.com/@luisvieira_gmr/building-large-scale-react-applications-in-a-monorepo-91cd4637c131

Comment: The fixed mode in Lerna is probably what I am looking for, I'll create a sample project and try this, thanks.